# Cannot map through state using ES6 in a ToDo App using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am working on a simple ToDo App and I am currently stuck on updating the state of my App.js Component.

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItem from "./ToDoItem";
import todosData from "./ToDoData";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loadedData: todosData,
    };
  }

  newChange = (id) => {
    const update = this.state.loadedData.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    // this is where my update variable will not update?
    console.log(update);
    this.setState({ loadedData: update });
  };

  render() {
    const todoComponent = this.state.loadedData.map((item) => (
      <TodoItem
        key={item.id}
        text={item.text}
        completed={item.completed}
        newChange={this.newChange}
      />
    ));

    return <div className="todo-list">{todoComponent}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my TodoItem Componenet (which I'm guessing will work fine once this state gets passed down correctly):

```
import React from "react";

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-item">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.props.completed}
          onChange={() => this.props.newChange(this.props.id)}
        />
        <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Lastly, my data is just an array made up of objects:

```
    const todosData = [
  {
      id: 1,
      text: "Take out the trash",
      completed: true
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      text: "Grocery shopping",
      completed: false
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      text: "Clean gecko tank",
      completed: false
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      text: "Mow lawn",
      completed: true
  },
  {
      id: 5,
      text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
      completed: false
  }
]

export default todosData
```

My biggest issue is WHY doesn't my **update** variable in my newChange() method get updated when I'm mapping through it?

When I console.log it, it shows the exact same data and the property that I want doesn't get updated?

loadedData is still the exact same as update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a prop (id) when creating your ToDoItems in App.js

You try to access it in ToDoItem, but you never set it...

So your render function in App should look like this:

```
render() {
    const todoComponent = this.state.loadedData.map((item) => (
      <TodoItem
        key={item.id}
        id={item.id}
        text={item.text}
        completed={item.completed}
        newChange={this.newChange}
      />
    ));

    return <div className="todo-list">{todoComponent}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: Wow thank you SO much. I can't believe I was just assuming the .id value would have just come from the setting of key to the child component. THANK YOUUUUUU!!!!!

Comment: Of course, you're welcome! But yeah it's confusing, key is actually not even a prop

Answer (score 1):

Danny, you was on the right track putting the `console.log(update)` there. This way you found that the function actually did not update the existing state in the map function.

To find out why, you need to check what's happening inside of the map function, and the first step is to test everything you use there. In this case you are using `this.props.id` and you can check it by putting console.log to check its value:

```js
  newChange = id => {
    console.log("id:", id); // NEW
    const update = this.state.loadedData.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    // this is where my update variable will not update?
    console.log(update);
    this.setState({ loadedData: update });
  };
```

Well, in this case it will print `id: undefined` when you try to click on the todo item because you did not actually pass it as a prop. The map function cycles through the todo items, but never finds any todo item that satisfies `if (todo.id === id)` (as it translates to `if (todo.id === undefined)` in your case)

The fix is simple, just pass the `id` as a prop to `todoComponent`

```js
  const todoComponent = this.state.loadedData.map(item => (
      <TodoItem
        id={item.id} // NEW
        key={item.id}
        text={item.text}
        completed={item.completed}
        newChange={this.newChange}
      />
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! This makes it very clear on a conceptual level! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're accidentally mutating state in your `newChange` handler when you perform:

```js
todo.completed = !todo.completed;
```

Instead, create a brand new `state` object slice:

```js
newChange = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    loadedData: this.state.loadedData.map((todo) => ({
      ...todo,
      completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed,
    })),
  });
};
```

Or, if you can't use the spread operator (`...`), try this:

```js
newChange = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    loadedData: this.state.loadedData.map((todo) =>
      Object.assign({}, todo, {
        completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed,
      })
    ),
  });
};
```

You can read more in the official React docs under "[The Power Of Not Mutating Data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)"

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a wrong answer. There is no problem with mutability here as map was used to create a new array. The problem is that `id` was not actually sent as a prop, resulting in `todo.id === undefined` comparison inside of the map function that never evaluates to `true`

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes a lot of sense!!! I appreciate your thoughtful response :)  @ivanD yes, I see that now but wouldn't it still be correct to not modify the original state?

Comment: Ah gotcha. I didn't think the mutation was safe even there, because objects are assigned by reference. Good catch finding the issue!

Comment: Avoiding mutating your state is always a good idea, and Reed is right about that. It just wasn't the reason for the error you got :)